# Huawei Nearby Search Error BUSINESS_VERIFICATION_FAILED

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have been using Site kit service to get nearby locations on the biases of Lat Lng.
But unfortunately this error appears out of no where.
[image: error log]

I had studied the documentation and error code which explain this
[image: error code description]

But the searched parameters are all those which are provided in documentations(for testing purpose) except the api key.

```
val searchService: SearchService = SearchServiceFactory.create(
        this, URLEncoder.encode(
            getString(R.string.huawei_maps_key),
            "UTF-8"
        )
    )
    val request = NearbySearchRequest()
    val location = Coordinate(48.893478, 2.334595)
    request.location = location
    request.query = "Paris"
    request.radius = 1000
    request.hwPoiType = HwLocationType.ADDRESS
    request.language = "fr"
    request.pageIndex = 1
    request.pageSize = 5
    request.strictBounds = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your following code

```
val searchService: SearchService = SearchServiceFactory.create(
        this, URLEncoder.encode(
            getString(R.string.huawei_maps_key),
            "UTF-8"
        )
    )
```

to：

```
   val apiKey: String?
        get() {
            // get apiKey from AppGallery Connect
            val apiKey = "your api key"

            // need encodeURI the apiKey
            return try {
                URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "utf-8")
            } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "encode apikey error")
                null
            }
        }


searchService = SearchServiceFactory.create(this, apikey)
```

Comment: Nope still the same.

Comment: hi@Uzair Mughal, what is your device model,  OS version and HMS Core APK version? And could you mind provide your apikey and detailed logs for us to check this issue?  You can get the complete log from the following command :`adb logcat –v time > D:\hwlog.log`

Comment: Sorry couldn't run the code right now.
but here are the details.

Device Model: JNY-LX1 
Device Name: Huawei nova 7i
android OS version: 11
HMS core version: 6.3.0.331

Comment: Is it secure to share api key here? @shirley

Comment: hi@Uzair Mughal, you could [Submit a ticket](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/support/feedback/#/) and provide your apikey for us to check.

Comment: I had submitted the ticket.
ticket id:D187119